# How to fix Visual Studio 2012 replace all dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open the `Find and Replace All` dialog the cursor is in the `Replace With` textbox instead of in the `Find What` textbox like it should be ala Visual Studio 2008.

This means I have to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to go to `Find What` - it's completely infuriating and makes no sense. I'd prefer that it's focused in `Find What` then I should <kbd>tab</kbd> into `Replace With` but I can't find setting for this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is so you can select the text you want to find in the IDE and then hit ctrl + shift + h. It will prepopulate the Find field with the text you selected and will take you directly to "Replace with" field so you can specify what you want to replace it with. I don't think there is any way you can change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and extend the dialog to use as replace. If pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> Focus is always in the correct(search) field.